# Pulseaudio doesn't record sound

Tags: pulseaudio, debian, recording

Pulseaudio fails to record any sound, even though the sound configuration
applications (both KDE and Gnome) correctly show the input level as I speak
something.

I am using the microphone built into my Logitech webcam. No microphone is
connected to the sound card built into the motherboard, and this device is
disabled for input.

I configured Pulseaudio using `pavucontrol`, as suggested in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13571/10950. I am running Debian Wheezy (Stable). Tried Gnome sound recorder and Skype for recording.

How can I fix it?

Comment: IMO, pulse itself doesn't record anything but some other application that process the sound. How exactly you say that doesn't "record"?

Comment: By *fails to record* do you mean you get a recording of silence? If so, what does pavucontrol show while you're recording?